# offlineimap: turn idle on

Tags: email, imap, push

I want to use idle (push email) with my IMAP.

I've read about IDLE mode in man, but I can't to turn it on.

Is it possible to find some manual about idle feature of offlineimap

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the included `/usr/share/offlineimap/offlineimap.conf` example configuration file, you have to set `idlefolders` to a list of folders to monitor.

```
########## Advanced settings

# ...

# In between synchronisations, OfflineIMAP can monitor mailboxes for new
# messages using the IDLE command. If you want to enable this, specify here
# the folders you wish to monitor. Note that the IMAP protocol requires a
# separate connection for each folder monitored in this way, so setting
# this option will force settings for:
#     maxconnections - to be at least the number of folders you give
#     holdconnectionopen - to be true
#     keepalive - to be 29 minutes unless you specify otherwise
#
# This feature isn't complete and may well have problems. See the manual
# for more details.
#
# This option should return a Python list. For example
#
# idlefolders = ['INBOX', 'INBOX.Alerts']
#
```

Comment: The documentation doesn't state if idlefolders requires the foldernames before or after nametrans. Do you happen to know anything about it?